# Android App doesn't compile due to invalid character constant

Tags: java, android, unicode, unicode-string

i have to work on an open source App, I have cloned the project from the repository but I get a compilation error at this point

```
 public static HashMap<Character, String> UNICODE_TRANS = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    static {
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã·', "/");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã—', "*");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã·', "/");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã—', "*");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â²', "^2");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â³', "^3");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â�´', "^4");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('âˆ’', "-");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Âµ', "micro");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ï€', "pi");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Î ', "pi");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â‚¬', "euro");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â¥', "japanyen");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â‚¤', "greatbritainpound");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('âˆš', "sqrt");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('âˆ›', "cuberoot");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â½', "1|2");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…“', "1|3");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…”', "2|3");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('Â¼', "1|4");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…•', "1|5");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…–', "2|5");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…—', "3|5");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…™', "1|6");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…›', "1|8");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…œ', "3|8");
        UNICODE_TRANS.put('â…�', "5|8");
    }
```

that say me Invalid character constant at every line

```
UNICODE_TRANS...etc
```

Why i cannot use these character constants. Is there something to set to avoid this compilation issue?

Comment: Those aren't valid characters...

Comment: @hexafraction but the app exist and is distributed in google play, I have cloned the latest stable repository... probably there is something to set to allow this syntax

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @hexafraction I'm using Eclipse + ADT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UNICODE_TRANS.put('Ã·', "/");
```

There are two characters in that literal, so it's not a character literal. What was meant was:

```
UNICODE_TRANS.put('÷', "/");
```

So what has probably happened is that the source code is saved as UTF-8, but is being interpreted by the compiler (and your text editor) as Windows code page 1252.

To fix the compiler for normal `javac` you use the flag `-encoding UTF-8`. The way you specify that for different IDEs and build systems will vary.

It is unfortunate that Java does not have in-file signalling for encoding. You can avoid the problem by ensuring source is pure ASCII, and including non-ASCII characters via escape:

```
UNICODE_TRANS.put('\u00F7', "/");
```